# Application getting crash while taking picture continuesly 2 to 3 times

Tags: objective-c

In my application I am uploading photos to Face Book. So, While taking picture from iPhone device 3G continuously two or three times my application getting crash and getting message as below

Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
(gdb)

I am not getting how to solve this can any one help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There really should be a backtrace and that error sounds a lot like your install is hosed;  you might try re-installing the dev tools and iOS SDK.

In any case, the description of your problem sounds like you might potentially be using all available memory and your app might be being jettisoned by the system.

If you rate limit the photos such that you can't take another photo until the first photo is uploaded, does the problem go away?

Do you have a memory warning hook in your app?  Is it getting fired?

Comment: Thanks for your responce.I didn't kept any limit for the photos.